# Powershell script to update xml node value not working on 2nd execution

Tags: powershell

I have written this powershell script to update xml node(UnitholderId) value for multiple xml files in a folder:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\tmp\unzipped\ *.xml | ForEach-Object { 
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_)

    $node = $xml.SelectNodes("//RecipientInfoList//UnitholderList")
    $node1 = $xml.SelectNodes("//RecipientInfoList//UnitholderList//List")

    foreach ($nodes in $node) {
        $NodeExists = $nodes.UnitholderId
        if (($nodes.UnitholderId = Null) || $NodeExists) {
            $nodes.UnitholderId = '987654'
        }
    }
    foreach ($nodess in $node1) {
        $NodeExists = $nodes.UnitholderId
        if (($nodes.UnitholderId = Null) || $NodeExists) {
            $nodess.UnitholderId = '987654'
        }
    }
    $xml.Save($_)
}
```

When I executed it for the first time , the values got updated but when I executed it again, it is not working. Can someone please help me on this.

I tried to execute for each file separately but I have the same issue. I am new to powershell scripting. I am not sure if I am missing something.

**Existing XML file:**

```xml
<DocumentDelivery>
  <Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>INVESTOR COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>Test123456</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>TestNameABC</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>TestAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>TestAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>TestAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>Lb-6012</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>123456</RecipientFaxNumber>
      <RecipientEmail>test@abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientContactPerson>
      </RecipientContactPerson>
    </Recipient>
    <RecipientInfoList>
      <UnitholderList>
        <UnitholderId>123456</UnitholderId>
        <List>
        <UnitholderId>123456</UnitholderId>
        </List>
      </UnitholderList>
    </RecipientInfoList>
  </Document>
</DocumentDelivery>
```

**Output xml file:**

```xml
<DocumentDelivery>
  <Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>INVESTOR COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>Test123456</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>TestNameABC</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>TestAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>TestAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>TestAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>Lb-6012</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>123456</RecipientFaxNumber>
      <RecipientEmail>test@abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientContactPerson>
      </RecipientContactPerson>
    </Recipient>
    <RecipientInfoList>
      <UnitholderList>
        <UnitholderId>987654</UnitholderId>
        <List>
        <UnitholderId>987654</UnitholderId>
        </List>
      </UnitholderList>
    </RecipientInfoList>
  </Document>
</DocumentDelivery>
```

Comment: i have added the image.please check @zett42

Comment: did you mean `-or` instead of `||` and `-eq $null` instead of `= Null` ?